# Python How to compute and store Residuals in a FOR-LOOP Regression

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, regression

The title outlines my problem for the following script(please, run it first and then read my final question):

Now the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import datetime    

tickers=['EXO.MI','LDO.MI']
end=datetime.date.today()
gap=datetime.timedelta(days=650)
start=end- gap

Bank=pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start=start,end=end)
bank_matrix=Bank['Adj Close']
bank_matrix=bank_matrix.dropna()

exor=bank_matrix['EXO.MI']
leonardo=bank_matrix['LDO.MI']

Regressione=pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((len(exor),3)),columns=['Intercetta','Hedge','Residuals'],index=bank_matrix['EXO.MI'].index)
lookback=20
Hedge=[]
Intercetta=[]
Residuals=[]

for i in range(lookback,len(exor)):
    reg=LinearRegression().fit(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i],bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][i-lookback+1:i])
    # Regressione.iloc[Regressione[i,'Hedge']]=reg.coef_[0]
    Hedge.append(reg.coef_[0])
    Intercetta.append(reg.intercept_)
    y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:])
    Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred)
Regressione=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Intercetta,Hedge,Residuals)),columns=['Intercetta','Hedge','Residuals'])
Regressione.set_index(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']].index[lookback:],inplace=True)
```

The code works however I have 2 questions:

1. Is that 'reg._residues' the real residuals from the Y(real value of 'EXO.MI') and y predicted?I ask that because the plot of residuals was everything but normally distributed or stationary
2. Guys I'm getting crazy: HOW CAN I COMPUTE THE everyday residuals in a 'FOR'LOOP ?????

I mean, I tried to:

1. make the difference between real y values and reg.predict
2. make the manual computation: y_predicted= Intercetta + Hedge*bank_matrix[['LDO.MI]]

But Python always report me problems. I honestly find very hard to understand how Python works for this....

Thanks

Comment: The snippet did not work. I edited in `import datetime` since that would not break the code in any way. Also `y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:])
    Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred)` raises an error on my end, but `y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:])
    Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:]-y_pred)` works fine. But I did not include that in the edit since it may work on your end due to possible different versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not 100% clear to me what you want to do here, but I hope this will get you somewhere.

First of all, your code runs fine if you just add `import datetime` in the beginning, and replace `y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:]) Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:].to_numpy()-y_pred)` with `y_pred=reg.predict(bank_matrix[['LDO.MI']][lookback:]) Residuals.append(bank_matrix[['EXO.MI']][lookback:]-y_pred)`.

Then you can visually check your residuals for each sub-period using:

```
for df in Residuals:
    df.plot.hist()
```

Using `Residuals[-3:]` will plot the last three residual series of your calculations:

[image]

You can also easily run a [Shapiro-Wilk](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html) test for normality for each of your residual series and append the results in a dataframe:

```
from scipy import stats
shapiro=[]

for df in Residuals[-3:]:
    shapiro.append(stats.shapiro(df[df.columns[0]].values))

df_shapiro = pd.DataFrame(shapiro)
```

`df_shapiro[0]` returns the W-statistic and `df_shapiro[1]` returns the p-values.

Take a closer look at the p-values using:

```
df_pVal=df_shapiro[1].to_frame()
df_pVal['alpha']=0.05
df_pVal.plot()
```

[image]

Take a look at [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-normality-tests-in-python/) for more information on how to use the test.

---

The question still remains what you're aiming to do here. A detailed explanation would be great. Until then, I hope my effort gets you a few steps further.

Comment: Very thanks Vestland.I followed your advices and I finally added this line:                res=[i.mean() for i in Residuals]                                                                                This provided me with an array of residuals of the same length as my time series for regression. At this point I could add:                                                                      plt.hist(bubu)
plt.plot(bubu)                                                                                                           and finally geot some reasonable graphs.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what happened with the revision of my code by admins, but here it misses one point:  Instead of using 'Residuals.append........' I had used another python function which is:  'Residuals.append(reg._residues)'.    Now you can finally understand why I did my first of my two questions about 'reg.residues'. Is that the mean for every sub- periods in my Residuals? Anyway thanks mate!